# ToExpression to Latex Parenthesis

Tags: expression-manipulation, latex

Everytime I use `ToExpression` to transform a TeX expression into mathematica input form, Mathematica always interprets parenthesis ('(' and ')') as square brackets, which has a differente meaning for expressions. I always have to manually change the expression. Also, it doesn't happen all the time.
Does anybody know what is going on and what can I do to fix this?
An Example:

```
ToExpression["A - \\frac{B (2+F)}{(1+C)} D", TeXForm]
```

This yields:

```
A - (D B[2 + F])/(1 + C)
```

I would like:

```
A - (D B(2 + F))/(1 + C)
```

Thanks.

Comment: In practice it may be easier to just fix the resulting Mathematica expression rather than get Mathematica to use the desired interpretation ... i.e. do a replacement similar to `s_[a_] :> s*a`.  Where do your TeX snippets come from?  Can you get MathML instead of TeX?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a LaTeX thin space `\,` as a multiplication symbol to enforce what you want:

```
ToExpression["A - \\frac{B\\,(2+F)}{(1+C)} D", TeXForm]

(* A-(B D (2+F))/(1+C) *)
```

As noted by rhermans, standard mathematical notation is ambiguous -- do the parentheses signify multiplication or function arguments? -- so the thin space is needed to remove the ambiguity.

As noted by march, if you want to consistently use parentheses for multiplication, you could define a function like

```
fromTeX[str_] := ToExpression[StringReplace[str, "(" -> "\\,("], TeXForm]
```

Now you can do

```
fromTeX["A - \\frac{B(2+F)}{(1+C)} D"]

(* A - (B D (2 + F))/(1 + C) *)
```

Comment: Can you imagine a systematic way of telling Mathematica to do this? I am aware that I may be asking for too much.

Comment: You need a way to differentiate the arguments of the function and the factorizing parenthesis. I guess that is why the space matters.

Comment: @user191919. You could do `StringReplace["A - \\frac{B (2+F)}{(1+C)} D", "(" -> "\\,("]` before converting the expression.